# undefined method 'createtoken'.intelephense(1013) laravel 8 API

Tags: undefined, laravel-8, laravel-passport, intelephense

I have added use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens; and use HasApiTokens in user model. Still intelephense is unable to recognise it in vs code. Also in postman when i run it it showns me error  `"message": "Personal access client not found. Please create one.", "exception": "RuntimeException", "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\vendor\\laravel\\passport\\src\\ClientRepository.php",` How can i solve it?
My line for creating token is `$token = Auth::user()->createToken("user_token")->accessToken;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command.

> php artisan passport:client --personal

Comment: I found its main reason. So, basically this is just an editor warning. It will not cause any error its just a visual studio code warning.